# How to print just the answer in the excel sheet using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am calculating some penalties and receivables based on respective data of a company and in the end I am calculating the net profit. Now, I want to put that net value inside an excel sheet(just that value only).
The code that I am using to print the end result is:

```
Sum1 = sum(OverPenalties)
Sum2 = sum(OverPenalties1)
Sum3 = sum(OverPenalties2)
Sum4 = sum(OverPenalties3)
Sum5 = sum(OverPenalties4)
Sum6 = sum(OverPenalties5)
Sum = Sum1 + Sum2 + Sum3 + Sum4 + Sum5 + Sum6
df['Total Penalty'] = Sum
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('penalty.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df = df[["Total Penalty"]]  # the columns you want in the excel
df.to_excel(writer, "SHEET_NAME", index=False)
writer.save()
```

But after running this code, I am getting a column "Total Penalty" and in that column many same values are printed

```
Total penalty
25643
25643
25643
25643
```

I just one single value to be printed in the an excel sheet.
expected output:

```
Total Penalty
25643
```

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Total Penality'],keep='last').to_excel(file_name.xlsx)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dataframe has several rows and when you assign the value to the new column 'Total penalty' you assign that value to all the rows. I think there must be another simple way to get only one row but you could try with [tail](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html):

```
df = df[["Total Penalty"]].tail(1)
```

[head](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) also works.

Answer (score 0):

You can get first row with the `df.iloc[0]`.

Usage:

```
import pandas as pd

my_dict = {'result' : ['25643', '25643', '25643', '25643']}

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df = df.iloc[0]
```